# Not all paths in ROS_PACKAGE_PATH[a series of ros package path] point to an existing directory:

Tags: ros-package-path

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I always come across with the problem that  Not all paths in ROS_PACKAGE_PATH [/home/lilimeng/fuerte_workspace/turtlebot:/home/lilimeng/fuerte_workspace/sandbox:/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks:/opt/ros/fuerte/share:/opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros] point to an existing directory:

- /home/lilimeng/fuerte_workspace/turtlebot

when I install segway_rmp and openni_kinect in my fuerte ROS in Ubuntu12.04. I have tried several times, such as ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=/home/lilimeng/fuerte_workspace/turtlebot, but it didn't work!!!

Looking for your help! I highly appreciate it!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/39465/not-all-paths-in-ros_package_path%5Ba-series-of-ros-package-path%5D--point-to-an-existing-directory:/) by [Lili Meng](https://answers.ros.org/users/2899/lili-meng/) on ROS Answers with karma: 286 on 2012-07-22

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2012-07-22**:
Do all of the paths (specifically /home/lilimeng/fuerte_workspace/turtlebot ) actually exist and you have permissions to read from those paths?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I got the answer, as the /home/lilimeng/fuerte_workspace/turtlebot does not exist. So I just changed to export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=/home/lilimeng/fuerte_workspace/sandbox:/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks:/opt/ros/fuerte/share:/opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros.

It finally works

---

Originally posted by [Lili Meng](https://answers.ros.org/users/2899/lili-meng/) with karma: 286 on 2012-07-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It is not recommended to manage the `ROS_PACKAGE_PATH` variable manually. The best way to keep `ROS_PACKAGE_PATH` organized and clean is to use [rosws](http://ros.org/wiki/rosws). Have a look at [this page](http://www.ros.org/wiki/fuerte/Installation/Overlays) for a quick tutorial.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-07-22

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2